# How to make the compilation of python source code reproducible

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, bytecode, pyc, binary-reproducibility

After installing jsonpickle on my machine
( pip install jsonpickle==1.4.1 --no-compile), I have noticed that the compilation of the `pandas.py` file in the `ext` subfolder is not always reproducible.

In the `ext` subfolder I executed the following bash code to compile all `.py` files to `.pyc` files:

`python -m compileall -d somereldir --invalidation-mode checked-hash`

this created a `pandas.cpython-37.pyc` file in the `__pycache__` subdirectory.
In the `__pycache__` subdirectory, I then executed:
`xxd pandas.cpython-37.pyc > hex1.hex`

If I do the abovementioned steps again and write the hexdump to `hex2.hex`, I noticed that there are two lines that do not match.

```
diff hex1.hex hex2.hex
288,289c288,289
< 000011f0: 0029 013e 0200 0000 723f 0000 00da 056e  .).>....r?.....n
< 00001200: 616d 6573 7213 0000 0029 0372 3300 0000  amesr....).r3...
---
> 000011f0: 0029 013e 0200 0000 da05 6e61 6d65 7372  .).>......namesr
> 00001200: 3f00 0000 7213 0000 0029 0372 3300 0000  ?...r....).r3...
```

I performed it several times and it appears that there are two "versions" of `.pyc` file, sometimes they match, sometimes they don't.

Because of this, I have several questions:

1. Why is there a difference in the `.pyc` files?
2. How can I make sure that the compiled `.pyc` file is always the same.
3. I checked some other python libraries and all of them produced reproducible `.pyc` files, so what is different for this `pandas.py` file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After splitting the `pandas.py` file in smaller parts and compiling these, I was able to determine the location of the problem on line 135:

> name_bundle = {k: v for k, v in meta.items() if k in {'name', 'names'}}

which answers the questions:

1. line 135 contains a set ( `{'name','names'}`).  The order of elements in a set is not necessarily preserved after compilation. Although [dictionaries preserve insertion order as of Python 3.7](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2017-December/151283.html), I could not find anything about order preservation of elements in sets for Python 3.7.
2. Set the environment variable PYTHONHASHSEED to a fixed value.
3. It is possible that these libraries do not contain any set.

Comment: w.r.t. Point 1, sets are unordered and so do not intentionally preserve insertion order

Comment: I understand, but the same could be said about dictionaries if it were not for that 3.7 update or do you see it differently?

Comment: As far as I understand it, the lack of ordering allows for performance gains, and if you ensured ordering you'd just have a list with unique entries in terms of performance.